# How to check for hollow_square if soldiers are in formation on board game?

Tags: c++, algorithm, game-engine, game-physics

In game ( `it is c++ board game like matrix with soldiers which can use formation`) soldiers can be deployed in formations. ( Only one soldier can be deployed on one cell on map/matrix, formation can be in 8 directions with angles 0, 45, 90, 135, 180, 225, 270, 315 degrees with x axis, when soldiers are in formation they are in adjacent cells, for example formation in 0 degree y is the same for all but x2 - x1 =1 and so on, on degree 45 y2-y1=1 and x2-x1=1 ).
Formations are line and hollow_square. I need on very efficient way to check if soldiers are in formation(soldier has x and y own position in class). For line I sort by x ( i have `std::list<std::pair<int,int> >` which represents positions of soldiers in unit) and check if diffrenece is 1 between adjancent (`in case 0, 180; in case 45, 135 ,225, 315 also check for difference for y is 1 or -1`). How to check for hollow_square if soldiers are in formation ?

(Like on this ugly image, to clarify)

[image]

Comment: Could you please add some pictures or ASCII art?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I have added image

Comment: @PaolaJ. check my answer . hope it be helpfull or give you some clue to do that

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
Make a copy of the board
Color the squares where you have soldiers using the first available color
For each square:
    if the square is white, then
        flood fill the board starting at this square with the next available color
        while flood filling, check whether all border squares are the soldier color
        if so, you have some closed formation. Otherwise, you just colored the unoccupied parts of the board.
```

The resulting colored board will have one color where there are troops and unique colors for the unoccupied and enclosed spaces. Something you might consider - are formations within formations allowed?